# VRTK Button to open Door

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

I'm new to using Unity and VRTK I do have a simple question. I'm making a game using Unity for the HTC Vive. I've created the level added doors and have gotten them to function exactly like the example doors in VRTK. I'm trying to find a way to make it so I hit a button and I can activate a door to open. I'm trying to use the VRTK button script but can't get it to work.

The door works by itself and is openable with the Vive controllers. I just can't figure out how attach the button to the door

Answer (score 0):

You could get a reference to the door's joint and just change the force on the joint to get it to auto open.